# Actionscript 3.0, TypeError: Error #1006: Value is not a Function

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

So I have an assignment for school due next week, but I'm getting an error. I asked my T/A about it, but she wasn't sure either. I've looked around on Google and this site for a while, but couldn't find anything to help me. The exact output/error is this:

```
1:false
usedfunction Function() {}
Maybe
TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
    at Assign6/usedAnswer()
    at Assign6/ballEndDrag()
```

The problem seems to be within the if statement

```
if(usedAnswer(msg)==false)
```

The program is not even tracing a value for

```
trace(usedAnswer(msg));
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks so much!!

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;


    public class Assign6 extends MovieClip
    {
        var ballDisplay:Array = new Array("Yes","No","It is certain!","Ask again","Try again","Better not","Most likely","Maybe","Reply is No","Doubtful","Outlook good");
        var usedList: Array = new Array();
        var magicInt:Number;

        public function Assign6()
        {

            magicBall.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ballStartDrag );
            magicBall.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, ballEndDrag );
        }

        // When the user presses the mouse down on magicBall, this function is called
        function ballStartDrag( evt: MouseEvent )
        {
            magicBall.startDrag( );
            magicBall.magicText.text = " ";
            magicBall.eightDisplay.text = "8";
        }

        // When the user lets the mouse up on magicBall, this function is called
        function ballEndDrag( evt: MouseEvent )
        {
            magicBall.stopDrag( );
            magicBall.eightDisplay.text = " ";
            var checkVal = false;
            while(checkVal==false){
                trace("1:" + checkVal);
                trace("used" + usedAnswer);
                var msg:String = randomAnswer();
                trace(msg);
                trace(usedAnswer(msg));
                    if(usedAnswer(msg)==false){
                        usedList.push(ballDisplay[magicInt]);
                        checkVal = true;
                        trace("2" + checkVal);
                }
            }
        }

        //Display random answer in magicText
        function randomAnswer( ):String
        {
            magicInt = Math.round(Math.random() * 11);
            magicBall.magicText.text = ballDisplay[magicInt];
            return ballDisplay[magicInt];
        }

        // Check whether answer has already been used
        // Returns true if answer is in usedList and false if not
        function usedAnswer( answer: String ): Boolean
        {
            var i = 0;
            for (i==0; i<usedList.length(); i++)
            {
                if (answer == usedList[i])
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be getting infinite loop which is the first problem you should fix.

Answer (score 2):

```
var i = 0;
for (i==0; i<usedList.length(); i++)
```

should be

`for (var i=0; i<usedList.length; i++)`

No?

Alternatively you can replace the for loop with [indexOf](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#indexOf()).

```
function usedAnswer( answer: String ): Boolean
{
    return usedList.indexOf(answer) !== -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's are errors in your for-loop and while loop.

replace this

```
for (i==0; i<usedList.length(); i++)
```

with

```
for (i=0; i<usedList.length; i++)
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the `while(checkVal = false)` change, that would cause an infinite loop!

Comment: Both of your solutions are plain wrong. Readers do not apply any of what fergoso shows in your code. length() is not valid, = is assignment not comparison.

Comment: @BotMaster: thanks, I've updated the length. I'm not sure if OP has fixed his problem. Awaiting OP's feedback.

Comment: `checkVal = false` is an assignment of a value, the while loop will never end.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Barış Uşaklı's answer:

Your `usedAnswer()`  function references `usedList` which is an Array type.  In Actionscript 3, Arrays have a `length` property that you can reference rather than a `length()` function that you can call.  You can read more in the [Array as3docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html).

Your practical fix is simply:

```
var i = 0;
for (i==0; i<usedList.length; i++)
```